# How do you autoconnect VPN in Windows Mobile 10?

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile, vpn

I want to enable my WP10 phone to automatically connect to hotspots.  However, I want my phone to automatically connect to a VPN when it does so, if this possible?

Comment: *When* do you want it to auto-connect? All the time, or in reaction to you doing something, such as launching an app?

Comment: when I connect to a wifi hotspot.